# The dialog box shown when clicking on the "Delete" button in the "Low Quality Posts" queue is not draggable

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts, popups

When I review posts in the "Low Quality Posts" queue, and I click on the "Delete" button, the dialog box that appears is not draggable. I noticed it on *Drupal Answers* and *English Language Learners*.

This doesn't happen with the dialog box on the "Close" queue.

I am currently using Google Chrome 26.0.1410.65 running on OS X 10.8.3. Stack Exchange's revision is 2013.4.12.642 in both the sites.